# Is there any way to read characters that satisfy certain conditions only from stdin in C++?

Tags: c++

I am trying to read some characters that satisfy certain condition from `stdin` with `iostream` library while leave those not satisfying the condition in `stdin` so that those skipped characters can be read later. Is it possible?

For example, I want characters in `a-c` only and the input stream is `abdddcxa`.

First read in all characters in `a-c - abca`; after this input finished, start read the remaining characters `dddx`. (This two inputs can't happen simultaneously. They might be in two different functions).

Comment: How do you know when you can stop reading characters that satify the certain condition?

Comment: Can you help us understand why you want to do this in this way? Is there some code that you do not have access to the source of? It seems like it would be much easier to just split up the stream and give the other function a stringstream to read from instead of cin.

Comment: Well, it's just a practice problem. I was wondering whether it would be possible without stringstream. Maybe I'd better stay with stringstream :)

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't it be simpler to read everything, then split the input into the two parts you need and finally send each part to the function that needs to process it?

Keeping the data in the stdin buffer is akin to using globals, it makes your program harder to understand and leaves the risk of other code (or the user) changing what is in the buffer while you process it.

On the other hand, dividing your program into "the part that reads the data", "the part that parses the data and divides the workload" and the "part that does the work" makes for a better structured program which is easy to understand and test.

You can probably use `regex` to do the actual split.

Comment: it's not really even akin, it *is* using globals in almost any implementation that works -- it would almost certainly be fiddling with buffers instead of with the actual input stream. ... and yeah, mangling your input is some serious action-at-a-distance.

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking for is the putback method (for more details see: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/putback/). You would have to read everything, filter the part that you don't want to keep out, and put it back into the stream. So for instance:

```
cin >> myString;

// Do stuff to fill putbackBuf[] with characters in reverse order to be put back

pPutbackBuf = &putbackBuf[0];
do{
    cin.putback(*(pPutbackBuf++));
while(*pPutbackBuf);
```

Another solution (which is not exactly what you're asking for) would be to split the input into two strings and then feed the "non-inputted" string into a stringstream and pass that to whatever function needs to do something with the rest of the characters.

Comment: I don't think this will work. `putback` is not required to work at all (it's allowed to fail as sreservoir puts it).

Comment: well, it's allowed to fail.

Comment: Well, do you have a better solution for him? I don't think there's any other way of leaving cin unmodified.

Comment: plz change the reference to e.g. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/putback as cplusplus.com is full of errors

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is not possible *in general*; `ungetc` and `putback` exist, but they're not guaranteed to work for more than one character. They don't actually change stdin; they just push back on an input buffer.

**What you could do instead** is to explicitly keep a buffer of your own, by reading the input into a string and processing that string. Streams don't let you safely rewind in many cases, though.

Answer (score 0):

No, random access is not possible for streams (except for fstream an stringstream). You will have to read in the whole line/input and process the resulting string (which you could, however, do using iostreams/`std::stringstream` if you think it is the best tool for that -- I don't think that but iostreams gurus may differ).